# In FOL are all functions also relations?

Tags: logic

In standard mathematics binary relations are treated as an expansion on the concept of the function, and as such we get into a difficult situation where 'xFy' could be the application of f on to x and y or a sentence xFy that states that x and y are related by F.

In FOL it is not clear to me how we avoid this issue, if feels inadequately formal to have such ambiguity. I assume this is solved in the interpretation, from what I've read it seems a relation can be treated distinctly to a standard function.

Comment: No; In FOL a *function* symbol is used to produce a term (a name) while a relation is used to form statements. Compare "the father of John" with "Tom is the father of John".

Comment: But we can replace functions with relations; instead of writing e.g. **x+y=z** we can introduce **Plus(x,y,z)** that holds when **z** is the sum of **x** and **y**.

Comment: I think this question is better suited for Math.SE since it is basic in first-order-logic mathematical theory.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA so for this very reasonable logical reason we draw a distinction between a relation and function in logic, something we tend not to do dealing with simple mathematical functions not defined in the context of a formal language.

Comment: Because predicate logic language was "abstracted" from current mathematical jargon, were we are accustomed to write x+y=z instead of plus(x,y,z).

Comment: Why is it a "difficult situation"? In set theory "y is an application of F to x" means the exact same thing as "x and y are related by F" (when F is a functional relation), namely xFy or (x,y) is an element of F. Binary relations/functions are sets of ordered pairs. In pure FOL there are only predicate symbols (interpreted as relations), and when function symbols are introduced (in [Skolemization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form)) they are distinguished from predicate symbols.

Comment: The English "John loves Mary" could be expressed as a relation Loves(john, mary) or as a function LoverOf(mary) the value of which is john. (Or perhaps more than one value if Mary has several lovers.) At a stretch you could perhaps say that a relation is a function whose range is a truth value, but in standard logic relations and functions are handled separately.

Comment: @Conifold that is clear, thank you. the 'mathematical' concept of a binary relation and function notation are not as clear because mathematics is not a completely formal language (however a very logical one nonethelss), however the definition of predicate symbols and function symbols is done in the intepretation, we could argue that the functions and binary relations are 'object's but the choice in whether we see them acting as functions or relations is done at the formal language level using predicate symbols and function symbols. This was the missing bit for me.

Answer (score 2):

> "'xFy' could be the application of f on to x and y"

No, I have never seen a function application written like this anywhere.

> "[FOL] it is not adequately formal"

Yes, it is. While it is true that the syntax for f(x,y) and R(x,y) is the same, formulas are always specified relative to a formal language where it is explicitly defined which symbols are function symbols and which ones are relation symbols.

In addition there is a convention to distinguish the two by giving function symbols lowercase and relation symbols uppercase letters.

Note also that the different nature of function and relation expressions makes them unambiguous in context: f(x,y) is a term and thus can only appear as an argument to a relation or equality; R(x,y) is a formula and thus can only appear between connectives and quantifiers. So there is no well-formed formula with an occurrence of ...(x,y) where both interpretations would be possible.

Comment: xFy would be like 1+1 or some other infix notation, its better when its clear that the function is an 'operator'

Comment: Where specifically did you find this?

Comment: I was trying to keep it general but I was more thinking along the lines of if given x=y how do we specifically know that this is a sentence and not of the form x+y, this is the kind of infix notation we'd use if we wanted to discuss the validity of x+1=2 or something of this type.

Comment: I don't disagree that it is often clear from context, but is there somewhere where this is made formal or the distinction made specific.

Comment: In FOL we don't use infix notation for function application.

Comment: By "context" I meant not something vaguely and implicitly implied by the topic, but unambiguously determined by the surrounding formula symbols. The distinction is entirely formal.

Comment: When he mentioned xfy he was talking about mathematics, not FOL. And besides, there are varieties of FOL that do allow for infix notation for functions.

Answer (score 1):

There are both syntactic and semantic differences between functions and relations. The differences are related.

In addition, relations are generally viewed extensionally, while in normal mathematics (that is, not mathematics that is specifically studying functions) functions are often viewed intensionally. When I say that functions are viewed intensionally I mean, for example, that f=x^2-y^2 is viewed as a different function from g=(x+y)(x-y) even though for all x, f(x)=g(x). If you are viewing the functions extensionally, then you would say that in this case, f and g are the same function. To avoid complications, I'll assume we are talking about extensional functions.

The syntactic difference between relations and functions is just that relation expressions occur in a different syntactic position than function expressions. In FOL, relation expressions are formulas while function expressions are terms. The same is true in math, although they aren't usually explicit about it. For example, if the mathematical text says something like

```
for all values greater than 1, <expr1><symbol><expr2>
```

Then you know that

```
<expr1><symbol><expr2>
```

represents a proposition, so

```
<symbol>
```

represents a relation. If the quote is something like

```
the value of <expr1><symbol><expr2> is always less than zero
```

then you know that

```
<expr1><symbol><expr2>
```

represents a value, so

```
<symbol>
```

must represent a function.

Semantically, there is a close relationship between functions and relations, but there isn't a unique relationship. What I mean by that is that there are different ways to view the relationship: you can view a relation R∈A×B over A and B as a function f∈(A×B→TV) mapping pairs of A and B to truth values such that ∀x,y.xRy⇔f(x,y)=T. Note that you can't in general view R as a function f∈(A→B) because there may be pairs such that xRy1 and xRy2, which can't be represented with a function. That is, f(x) is either y1 or y2; it can't be both.

Alternatively you can view a (total) function f∈(A→B) as a relation R∈A×B such that ∀x,y.xRy⇔y=f(x).